# Repeat an array object with key and values with map in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Hi i want to repeat an array object including object keys(once) and all the object values with map function

```
[
   { name: 'abc', age:'1' },
   { name: 'def', age:'2' },
   { name: 'ghi', age:'3' }
]
```

and  i want repeat like this

```
name  age
abc    1
def    2
ghi    3
```

thanks

Comment: You just need to print the array ?

Comment: Well, if all the objects share the same keys with the first one, then just get the fields of the first one, and loop for all rows

Comment: Why is the restriction to only map()?

Comment: not only map any other also fine, i want to repeat in a table row

Comment: Please update the question with the attempted code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 let data = [
   { name: 'abc', age:'1' },
   { name: 'def', age:'2' },
   { name: 'ghi', age:'3' }
  ]

  rows = [] ; for (i in data[0]) {rows.push(i)}
```

Here you can display rows using "rows" array
Below code is to display columns

```
   data.map(item => {rows.map(row => {console.log(item[row])})})
```